# Is there a better way to accomplish this? Excel copy-pasting using conditional statement based on formatting conditions of the cells above and below

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

How can I achieve the after where the dates are copied next to the appropriate expenses without having to manually copy paste? I guess the logic is that all the charges copy the date before them which is in bold. Once a new date pops up, the new date is copied down. I am not sure how I would achieve this.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: I notice that the first line for personB has "PersonB" listed in both columns A and C, but it's not the case for PersonA. Is there a standard way this will be listed? Which is representative of your actual data?

Comment: Select the range you want and select Ctrl+G- Special- Blanks- select all Blank cells- enter = and ↑ up arrow- Ctrl+Enter, it will fill all cells automatically.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the [tour]. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. Also familiarize yourself with the [help], especially regarding [asking](https://superuser.com/help/asking).

Comment: And since your question has been answered, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example.  You can do this a bunch of ways. The quickest might just be to open the VBEditor, open the Immediate Window (CTRL+G), paste this text and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
Range("B2:B20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=IF(A2=C2,"""",B1)"
```

(Adjust that starting range as necessary. Note that you must start at row 2 though, but change the 20 to whatever the end of your data is)

[image]